# Convert AEST time to UTC format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the date string `Wed Aug 03 10:52:06 AEST 2016` and want to convert it into UTC time in JavaScript. I know I could probably do some string manipulation but my program will potentially be receiving date information from many different timezones in this format so want to be able to construct a universal formatter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use a library like moment.js

Comment: yeah I'm just struggling to figure out how to use to achieve what I'm after.

Comment: I've added an example how to use it , see  my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
var stringDate='Wed Aug 03 10:52:06 AEST 2016';

var date  = moment(stringDate,'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss AEST YYYY');
var dateInUTC=moment().utc(date)

console.log(dateInUTC.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```